# Having trouble with Facebook PHP SDK on mobile devices

Tags: authentication, facebook-php-sdk

I'm having trouble with Facebook SDK on mobile devices, I hope someone here can shed light for me.

I have js sdk doing a FB.getLoginStatus and if `response.status == 'connected'` then open a pop-up iframe. The pop-up iframe uses PHP sdk to do `$facebook->getUser()`, which is returning 0 every time, even after redirecting to `$facebook->getLoginUrl()`. What is surprising about this is that when redirecting to the PHP `$loginUrl`, there is no login dialog, it simply returns to the redirect_uri supplied, but the `$facebook->getUser()` is still 0, and when I try `$facebook->api('/me')` and catch the exception, it says *An active access token must be used to query information about the current user*.

I have tried `$facebook->getAccessToken()`, still doesn't work. I have also tried posting the JS SDK `response.authResponse.accessToken` back to PHP and putting it into `$facebook->setAccessToken()`, that doesn't work either. What the hell is going on? I am having no problems like this on a desktop browser, it is only on mobile devices..

To clarify, this is a script I am using to test:

```
<?php

require_once(__DIR__ . '/../facebook-sdk-3.2.2/facebook.php');  

$facebook = new Facebook(array(  
    'appId'  => '[private]',
    'secret' => '[private]',
'cookie' => true
));

$redirectUri = 'https://www.[private].com/ios-test.php';

$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginURL(array(
    'scope' => 'publish_stream,publish_actions,email',
    'redirect_uri' => $redirectUri
));

echo '<a href="'.$loginUrl.'" target="_top">'.$loginUrl.'</a><br />';

var_dump($facebook->getUser());

exit(__FILE__.__LINE__);
```

However, when testing on the Facebook app for iPhone, the user id is 0 and when clicking the `$loginUrl`, I am not presented with an auth dialog but I am taken back to the same page where user id remains 0. Same happens on Android native browser. When using Chrome on iPhone, the correct Facebook user ID is displayed.

I really need help with this, I have spent over four hours banging my head against this wall and scouring the internet, there is nothing out there that helps. Someone suggested I try Stack Overflow, I hope they are right!

Comment: I see someone voted it down, but no-one has stepped in to help. What sort of people visit this forum?

Answer (score 0):

I've got exact same issue. I got it working on all mobile browsers by specifying the direct url and not the canvas url when generating the facebook auth url. But it doesn't seem to work on iphone......